# Sum of items in nested python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, nested

I have a nested dictionary

```
mydict = {
 'school1': {
    'grades1': [78, 96, 80], 
    'grades2' : [81, 86, 90]}, 
 'school2': {
    'grades3' : [60, 65, 70],
    'grades4' : [67, 98, 100]}
}
```

I want to find the sums of 'grade' sub dictionary I have and can't quite figure it out. I do not want to hard code

```
sum(mydict['school1']['grades1'])
```

and so on.

'for schools in my_dict2:

```
print(schools)
for grades in my_dict2[schools]:
    print(grades)
    for values in my_dict2[schools][grades]:
        print(sum(values))`
```

I got to the values, but trying to take the sum of values here results in TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Any help much appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: What output do you expect? Can you also post your tries?

Comment: I want to find the sums of the grades and then create a new dictionary (or swap the grades with sum of grades) with the different grades and the respective sums (or means). The goal right now is to access the grades values and be able to manipulate them (take the sum, average, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to loop through dictionaries in python is to use `dict.values()`, `dict.keys()`, or its combined cousin `dict.items()`. So a purely `for-loop` implementation might look like so:

```
sumGrades = []
for school in mydict.values():
    sumGrades.append(0)
    for grade in school.values():
        sumGrades[-1] += sum(grade)
```

And converting to list comprehension:

```
sumGrades = [sum(sum(g) for g in s.values()) for s in mydict.values()]
```